# WooCommerce: automatic sorting of product variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

How can we change the sorting of product variations automatically? We don’t want to use Drag and Drop, because we upload the Articles via JTL WaWi (our ERP-System) and we have nearly thousand variations.

The current sorting of the variations is a bit strange, e.g: https://hms4you.com/produkt/jaca-boot-3/ -> look for “Größe”, the numbers are some kind of random. In Our inventory, they are sorted ascending.

What’s the best way to sort the articles ascending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually an Error an error with my PHP setup: I used PHP5 instead of PHP7 and PHP7 uses some kind of other sorting. After upgrade to PHP7 all problems with JTL sync were solved.

Source of the error was JTL, not WooCommerce.